# How to receive an unknown struct, unmarshal a YAML file using this unknown struct, and return the same struct

Tags: go

I'm trying to create some code that will allow a random YAML file passed in, with a struct to unmarshal that YAML file (both the YAML content & struct can be dynamic). This should be passed into a function, and returned with a populated struct matching the one passed in.

1. Is this possible? 2) How? I've tried a few things using interface{} as the parameter, but the returned result is an empty struct.

I've noticed that the pointer value that I pass in is different to the one I get returned. So I'm assuming that somewhere... I'm creating a new struct and returning that new empty struct?

Theoretically, ReadMyStruct function will be a separate module, that I can pass empty structs & YAML files to, and get back populated structs - dynamically.

Heres what I've been testing:

With a YAML like:

```
name: "Jim"
age: "39"
pets:
 - "Snake"
 - "Dog"
```

Code (ReadMyStruct being in a separate module, but I'll deal with that roadblock when I get to it):

```
type MyStruct struct {
    name   string     `yaml:"name"`
    age    int        `yaml:"age"`
    pets   []string   `yaml:"pets"`
    blah blah <-- could be X number more fields to this struct
}

func ReadMyStruct(yamlFile string, myStructure interface{}) (interface{}, error) {

    fmt.Println("Before unmarshal:", &myStructure)
    fh, err := os.ReadFile(yamlFile)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if err := yaml.Unmarshal(fh, &myStructure); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    fmt.Println("After unmarshal:", &myStructure)
    return myStructure, nil
}

func main() {
    var myStruct = new(MyStruct)
    returnedStruct, _ = ReadMyStruct("heresmyyaml.yaml", myStruct)
    fmt.Println(returnedStruct.name)
}
```

Output:

```
Jim
```

Comment: You're taking the address of the `myStructure` interface value, `myStructure` already contains a pointer. You also need to export to struct fields for this to work at all.

Comment: I'm not sure how to add a 'solved' answer on stack overflow. But this seems to have fixed it. Removing the '&' everywhere in ReadMyStruct gave me exactly what I was looking for.